# Quantile regression prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels, quantile-regression

I have used [statsmodels.formula.api.quantreg](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.quantreg.html) to predict on the test set. While running this method I got an unexpected error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-12e0d345b0fc> in <module>
----> 1 test['ypredL'] = model1.predict( test ).values
      2 test['FVC']    = model2.predict( test ).values
      3 test['ypredH'] = model3.predict( test ).values
      4 test['Confidence'] = np.abs(test['ypredH'] - test['ypredL']) / 2

~\anaconda3\envs\knk\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in predict(self, exog, transform, *args, **kwargs)
   1081                        '\n\nThe original error message returned by patsy is:\n'
   1082                        '{0}'.format(str(str(exc))))
-> 1083                 raise exc.__class__(msg)
   1084             if orig_exog_len > len(exog) and not is_dict:
   1085                 import warnings

AttributeError: predict requires that you use a DataFrame when predicting from a model
that was created using the formula api.

The original error message returned by patsy is:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

The intriguing part is that the same predict was run on the training set and it worked perfectly fine! Here is the code for the training part:

```
model1 = quantreg('FVC ~ Weeks+Percent+Age+Sex+SmokingStatus',
                           train).fit(q = 0.25)
model2 = quantreg('FVC ~ Weeks+Percent+Age+Sex+SmokingStatus',
                           train).fit(q = 0.5)
model3 = quantreg('FVC ~ Weeks+Percent+Age+Sex+SmokingStatus',
                           train).fit(q = 0.75)

train['y_predL'] = model1.predict(train).values
train['y_pred'] = model2.predict(train).values
train['y_predH'] = model3.predict(train).values
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Is `test` a DataFrame and does it have the same structure than `train`? When showing data, it is better to copy paste it instead of publishing a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, test is a DataFrame and it has a similar structure to train. I will copy-paste next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error *'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'* is right, but it is difficult to understand. So, what it really means is that there must be a conflict in dtypes in between the training and the test set.
In the question, there was a dtype mismatch between the *Weeks* in the training set and the test set.

dtype of Train-Weeks is *int*, and dtype of Test-Weeks is *str*.

Comment: Good point you answered your question. Hence the need of a [mcve] if you wish other can help you, because without the ability of reproducing your issue it is hard to tell what is going wrong. Have a good day. Cheers.